# What are the technical reasons of updating SuperSU?

Tags: updates, superuser

After rooting a device , and installing SuperSU ( Chainfire or Coding Code Mobile Technology ) and everything is fine , let's say an update to SuperSU is  available say after a few months

**Do I need to update ? What are the downsides , if any , if I don't ?**

My understanding is that I don't need to but wanted to be sure *with technical reasons / explanation* . Googling didn't help.

**Edit:** This is not related to the problems with Ver 2.80 or 2.81 , <s>this is a generic question</s>

**Edit 2:** From Generic to specific - after reading changelogs, I don't understand whether I should `Ver 2.79` to a later version on Moto X Play , 6.0. Can this be clarified ?

Comment: Chainfire does still post up-to-date changelogs on the (now obsolete) [XDA thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=64916199&postcount=3) - I'd say one should look at these changelogs for crucial global/device-specific bugfixes before deciding to update.

Comment: @AndyYan : That's what I normally do before updating any app - in this case at times , the reasons given in logs aren't exactly clear if they apply to my device. Updates in general address bug fixes , yes, but I am not sure if that should be the only reason to update

Comment: What other reasons do you expect? Just asking. There certainly will be few if any "feature" updates for SuperSU; security is a much bigger concern here.

Comment: @AndyYan : you are right in a sense. I am on 2.79, Moto X Play should I upgrade to later version is another way of asking. Change log didn't help in figuring out. If you can answer that I can edit accordingly.

Comment: The way I see it, just do a nandroid backup and try it out. The only thing preventing me from upgrading softwares on my devices is they probably won't work (or not as well as before); having something immediate to fall back to is enough to let me try. Since you're already on a CCMT-developed version, I don't see any trust issues either.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to update. But, it is always a good habit to keep your device up to date.

If you do not want to download so frequently, then see the change log of the updates, and decide whether you want to update or not.

Comment: You may be right but I am looking for *technical reasons* - edited question to make it clear